# How to create a profile which uses both HDMI and Audio Stereo output

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

How to create a profile which uses both HDMI and Audio Stereo output?
Normally, when I want to use HDMI, have to open pavucontrol and choose HDMI in Configuration tab.
And when I want to go back to Line out i have to go and choose Audio Stereo output again.
How can I use both of the output sources at the same time? Since they are in different profiles I cannot sync them both.

---

Running `pacmd list-cards`

```
1 card(s) available.
    index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 6
    properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA Intel PCH"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA Intel PCH at 0xdf220000 irq 128"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "a2f0"
        device.product.name = "200 Series PCH HD Audio"
        device.form_factor = "internal"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Built-in Audio"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Input (priority 32833, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Output (priority 39268, available: unknown)
        output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Analog Stereo Duplex (priority 39333, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 38668, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 38733, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output (priority 5700, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 5765, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output (priority 600, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra2+input:analog-stereo: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 3) Output + Analog Stereo Input (priority 665, available: unknown)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <output:analog-stereo>
    sinks:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo/#2: Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    sources:
        alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.3.analog-stereo.monitor/#2: Monitor of Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
    ports:
        analog-input-front-mic: Front Microphone (priority 8500, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (priority 8700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
        analog-output-lineout: Line Out (priority 9000, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                
        analog-output-speaker: Speakers (priority 10000, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-speakers"
        analog-output-headphones: Headphones (priority 9900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-headphones"
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: yes)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
                device.product.name = "HDMI"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-2: HDMI / DisplayPort 3 (priority 5700, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
```

Also, using xrandr i can see I'm using HDMI-2, while pacmd list-cards running with HDMI profile says i am using hdmi-output-0

Answer (score 0):

Run `paprefs`, if you do not have it, it can be installed with apt.

The last tab is `Simultaneous Output`, there is an option there that will add a new virtual device to simultaneously play audio to **all** devices.

Then back in `pavucontrol` you should be able to select the simultaneous virtual device.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, the HDMI and Line out are in different profiles, hence they do not show together as one. Hence i mentioned I cannot sync them both. paprefs can simultaneously produce output ONLY if both are in the same profile

Comment: I see, 2 different outputs from the same sound card.